# Oracle equivalent to Ingres inquire_sql or inquire_ingres?

Tags: c, oracle, ingres

I'm converting some legacy embedded-Ingres C code to work against Oracle.  I've found references to functions "`inquire_ingres()`" and "`inquire_sql()`," which, per the docs at http://docs.ingres.com/ingres/9.3/sql-reference-guide/2275-inquiresql-function, allow a program to gather  runtime information about the status and results of the last SQL statement that the program issued.

Does Oracle provide similar convenience functionality, or am I going to have to just paw around some more in the innards of `sqlca` as I suspect I'm going to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the answer is: you have to paw around in the innards of `sqlca`.  There's a lot of good information buried in that struct though -- check out http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-proc.html#sqlca for some details.